# How can I avoid infinite recursion in this FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I have a table `tbl` which has a `dirty: boolean` column. During the transaction, for certain rows this flag is set to `true`. Then, I have the following trigger:

```
create function tbl_process() returns trigger as
$$ begin
    -- first, do something for all rows with dirty flag set to true
    ...

    -- then, reset the dirty flag
    update tbl set dirty = false where dirty = true;

    return null;
end $$ language plpgsql;

create trigger tbl_process after update on tbl for each statement execute procedure tbl_process();
```

The problem here is that the second query (`update tbl set dirty = false where dirty = true`) calls the trigger recursively. This keeps on going until we get a stack overflow.

Is there a way to avoid this? And also, why are we running into recursion? In the first iteration, we mark all rows as `dirty = false`, so in the second iteration, there should be no rows for which `dirty = true`?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: I don't know your rask, but you can use `WHEN(condition)`

Comment: I agree with Vao Tsun: maybe don't fire the trigger if `dirty` is changed? Or only fire it for specific columns? What exactly are you doing with those rows? Maybe a before row level trigger is a better choice (but that depends on what you need to do)

Comment: I thought about that, but I am not sure how to do that. How can you combine `WHEN` with `FOR EACH STATEMENT`?

Comment: for statement `WHEN` condition can't reference `NEW` or `OLD` - so my advise is not usable  I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this below statement at the start of function body

```
IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
```

like

```
create function tbl_process() returns trigger as
$$ begin
    IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
    update tbl set dirty = false where dirty = true;

    return null;
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: That's a neat trick, but I don't understand why I need that. In the first iteration, we set all rows with `dirty = true` to `false`. In the second row, there shouldn't be such rows present?

Comment: depending on some scenarios trigger runs recursively. in order to stop that its built in function pg_trigger_depth() to check depth of trigger. only if its equal to 1 its first time. when it goes higher 2,3,4... it means recursive. to this check will stop it

Answer (score 0):

You could validate if the NEW value for this field is true before updating. If it is set to false you shouldn't have to do anything.

But, why do you process all records where this field is set? Because of this trigger there only should be this one, because in the end it is resetted.
And if you need to update the current record you can do that properly by updating the NEW.dirty to false.

Comment: Please not that this is a `for each statement` trigger, not a `for each row`.

Comment: @Samuel True, and I think Glenner003 missed that in your question, but the same logic as in this answer still works: you just have to make the trigger exit immediately if no rows exist where `dirty` is true.

Comment: @hvd I understand what he is saying, but it confuses me. Shouldn't the `where` clause in `update tbl set dirty = false where dirty = true` already cover that? I can't see why I am running into recursion, because in the second iteration, all rows should have `dirty` set to `false`?

Comment: @Samuel An update that affects 0 rows is still an update statement that executed successfully, so still causes `for each statement` triggers to be executed. This is called out [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: Ouch, I did not realize that. Thank you for reminding me of that, I get it then. I gat @latlong's proposal to exit immediately on `trigger depth <> 1` is fine then.